# Getting AWS Credentials in Jenkins Parameters script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, plugins

We are using Jenkins and have got **AWS Credentials** stored in **Jenkins Credential store**.

I am now configuring a Build job to get the list of APIs from AWS to allow users to select the API (from parameter dropdown). To do this, I am writing a groovy script to get the list of AWS APIs. E.g. 
`aws apigateway get-rest-apis`

But in order to run the above command, I need to first get the AWS credentials from the Jenkins credentials store. How can I do this?

(Correct me if I am wrong, the script which is going to be part of Extended parameter is going to run on Jenkins master node (and not on the Slave node) and not sure how do I get the AWS credentials)

Comment: You can create IAM role and setup aws cli on build server: aws configure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone's benefit, I used command like

```
env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${YourIDVariable} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${YourKeyVariable} aws apigateway get-rest-apis
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Adding below in groovy script:

env.AWS_CREDENTIAL_ID="user_id"

user_id is id that is set in credentials for AWS account
[image]

Comment: thanks. for everyone's benefit, I used command like
`env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${YourIDVariable} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${YourKeyVariable} aws apigateway get-rest-apis` and it worked